# accessing a dictionary with an item from a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

I am trying to access a dictionary in python. I have a list containing airport codes and for each code I want to use the code to enter in my dictionary and get the airport information that is in airportDict from my Airport class

```
    for i in range(len(itinerary) - 1):
         a1 = Airport.airportDict.get(itinerary[i])
```

I used something like this earlier in my code to make a weighted directed graph.

```
    graph = {}
    for i in range(len(airportInput)):
         graph[airportInput[i]] = {}
         a1 = Airport.airportDict.get(airportInput[i])
```

this worked fine but in the one above I get an error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

In the above case airport input is also a list and was declared as such

```
    airportInput = [row[0], row[1], row [2], row[3], row[4]]
```

Just for more clarification this is the main function that I am trying to use

```
     def shortestPath (row):

        airportInput = [row[0], row[1], row [2], row[3], row[4]]
        aircraftInput = row[5]
        graph = createGraph(airportInput, aircraftInput)
        airportsToVisit = [row[1], row [2], row[3], row[4]]
        originAirport = [row[0]]
        iteneries = permute(airportsToVisit)
        for perm in iteneries:
           #perm.insert(0, originAirport)
           perm.extend([originAirport, perm[0]])
           print(perm)
           print(cost(perm, aircraftInput))
```

my permute function is

```
   def permute(destinationList): 
      permutationTuples = permutations(destinationList) 
      return list([list(_) for _ in permutationTuples])
```

and cost is

```
  def cost(itinerary, aircraft):
     air = Aircraft.airplaneDict.get(aircraft)
     if air.units == 'imperial':
         fuelCapacity = float(air.range) * 1.60934
     else:
         fuelCapacity =float(air.range)
     distanceList = []
     for i in range(len(itinerary) - 1):
         a1 = Airport.airportDict.get(itinerary[i])
         country = a1.country
         currencyCode = CurrencyCode.currencyCodeDict.get(country).currencyCode
         toEuroRate = float(currencyRate.currencyRateDict.get(currencyCode).toEuroRate)
         lat1 = a1.lat
         long1 = a1.long
         a2 = Airport.airportDict.get(itinerary[i])
         country = a2.country          
         lat2 = a2.lat
         long2 = a2.long
         distance = greatcircledist(long1, lat1, long2, lat2)
         if distance > fuelCapacity:
             return none
         else:
             distance *= toEuroRate
        distanceList.append(distance)
     return sum(distanceList)
```

Comment: Are you saying that airportDict is a dictionary? I think its definitely a dictionary

Comment: @TCouch that's not the case, since a dictionary is also not hashable. It seems that somewhere `airportInput[i]` is also a list, but if it returned a dictionary it would still throw `TypeError`

Comment: If you hope to get any useful answer, please post a MCVE.

Comment: Could you also provide an example of `itinerary`? I have a feeling that might be the culprit.

Comment: @palivek I think it may be my permute function that it my issue.

Comment: please fix your indentation, it is supposed to be python code

Comment: @depperm sorry I'm new to this. All fixed now!

Comment: @rhanly, what does `permutations` return, a sequence of lists perhaps?

Comment: what is in `row`?

Comment: @depperm row is a row of a file `def readRouteData(fileName): #read test route data file and load into the memory
    with open(fileName, encoding = "utf8", errors = 'replace') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            shortestPath(row)`

Comment: @palivek I do not understand by what you mean by permutations? The airportInput is printed as `['DUB', 'LHR', 'SYD', 'JFK', 'AAL']` and the permutation is printed as `['LHR', 'SYD', 'JFK', 'AAL', ['DUB'], 'LHR']`

Comment: @rhanly, this line `permutationTuples = permutations(destinationList) `.

Comment: @palivek I get <itertools.permutations object at 0x1109db258>

Comment: @rhanly, all right, could you also provide the **full** error with traceback.

Comment: `File "/rosannahanly/workspace_20230/comp30670Project/tests/testDistance.py", line 23, in <module>
    readRouteData('..//files/testRouteData.csv')
  File "/Users/rosannahanly/workspace_20230/comp30670Project/tests/testDistance.py", line 16, in readRouteData
    shortestPath(row)
  File "/Users/rosannahanly/workspace_20230/comp30670Project/atlas.py", line 132, in shortestPath
    print(cost(perm, aircraftInput))
  File "/Users/rosannahanly/workspace_20230/comp30670Project/atlas.py", line 142, in cost
    a1 = Airport.airportDict.get(itinerary[i])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: @rhanly, it seems that `itinerary[i]` is a list, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: `def permute(destinationList): 
        permutationTuples = permutations(destinationList) 
        #print(permutationTuples)
        return list([list(_) for _ in permutationTuples])  ` Perhaps this function is the issue?

Comment: @rhanly, what does `print(perm)` print?

Comment: @palivek `['LHR', 'SYD', 'JFK', 'AAL', ['DUB'], 'LHR']`

Comment: @rhanly Aha, now I know - posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @rhanly, what does print(perm) print?
>
> @palivek ['LHR', 'SYD', 'JFK', 'AAL', ['DUB'], 'LHR']

There's your problem. If `i == 4`, then `itinerary[i] == ['DUB']`. `['DUB']` is a list, which is not a valid dictionary key, because it's mutable.

Comment: Ah I see, so I just need to think of a way of appending dublin to the start and end of each permutation.. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your trying to use a list as a Key to a dictionary.

`airportInput = [row[0], row[1], row [2], row[3], row[4]]`

Error is probably here `graph[airportInput[0]]`, and also here `a1 = Airport.airportDict.get(airportInput[0])`

You are effectively trying to do, `graph(row[0])`

The error suggests `row[0]` is of type List?

Either way, try adding a few print statements to see what the actual values are just before the exception is raised. I think you will be surprised.

As an aside, do you know about splices... you can `airportInput = row[0:5]`. If you haven't already, perhaps take the time to go through the latest Python tutorial [Python 3 Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) or [Python 2 Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html). It doesn't take long, but it should really help you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So for that part my code is working it's when I try to use my permutation list to access my dictionary I'm getting the error. Thanks for the tip also!